# Color on Shortcode insert that creates a button

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to insert a button with shortcode into my Elementor editing tool.
Creating the button works, but it seems to take the color from the theme, which I can't seem to change.
So I was trying to edit the shortcode to force the color..

Original without color:
Live Chat
Added color.
Live Chat
But it doesn't change anything.

Is there anything else I need to update or is the coding incorrect?

thanks

Comment: Please add your code blocks so we can see what you did.

Comment: sorry, I thought i did add that.

<button class='openLiveSupportiChat'>Live Chat</button>